# Finite index quotient group, lattice crypto

Tags: lattice-crypto

A $m$-dimentional full-rank integer lattice $\Lambda\in\mathbb{Z}^{m}$ can be defined as the set of all *integer* linear combinations of $m$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ basis vectors $\textbf{B}=\{\vec{b}_{1},\ldots,\vec{b}_{m}\}\subset\mathbb{Z}^{m}$:
$$\lambda=\mathcal{L}(\textbf{B})=\left\{\textbf{B}\vec{c}=\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} c_{i}\vec{b}_{i}:\vec{c}\in\mathbb{Z}^{m}\right\}$$

*Now, we want to consider group theoretic definition of a lattice*:
$m$-dimentional full-rank integer lattices $\Lambda\in\mathbb{Z}^{m}$ are discrete additive subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^{m}$ having finite index, i.e., the quotient group $\frac{\mathbb{Z}^{m}}{\Lambda}$ (its elements are sets) is finite.
[David Cash, Dennis Hofheinz, Eike Kiltz, Chris Peikert."Bonsai Trees, or How to Delegate a Lattice Basis", In Journal Of Cryptology 2012]

**Question 1**: Is there any intuitive concrete example of this quotient group modulo a lattice, $\frac{\mathbb{Z}^{m}}{\Lambda}$,?

A lattice is $\color{red}{infinite}$, but lattice crypto actually uses the $\color{red}{finite\ Abelian\ group}$ $\frac{\mathbb{Z}^{m}}{\Lambda}$. It works modulo the lattice $\Lambda$.
[Phong Nguyen. "Lattice based Cryptography Slides" In Post Quantum Cryptography Winter School 2016]

**Question 2**: Does $\frac{\mathbb{Z}^{m}}{\Lambda}$ being a finite group has any uses in lattice cryptography (like in hardness of some problems, or in security reductions, ...)? Or it happens to $\Lambda$ has a finite index, and it's just a mathematical property (not interesting in cryptography)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finite-index property is not fundamental from a mathematical perspective.
Note that not all mathematical lattices are finite-index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. This is a property of what are called "full rank" lattices.
As a trivial example, the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus \{0\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$ has index $|\mathbb{Z}^n / \mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\oplus \{0\}|= |\mathbb{Z}| = \infty$.
Often it is natural to define mathematical lattices as (non-full rank) lattices in some higher-dimensional space, see for example the definition of the Leech lattice (a rank 24 latice) in 26-dimensional Lorentzian space.

For cryptography though, the property is fundamental.
In cryptography, when working with some algebraic object $G$, it is important we can encode representations of elements of $g$ in some fixed amount of space.
As a trivial example, if we wanted to do cryptography over $\mathbb{Z}$, and used a variable-length encoding (say binary for simplicity), then if an adversary sees a message of length 1, they know it is either $0$ or $1$, vs a length 100 message, which is neither of these.
In short, variable length encodings introduce a side-channel, which can hurt security.

Lattices $L$ are by default infinite-size objects, i.e. $|L| = \infty$.
Fortunately, most lattices are periodic, in the sense that one can write

$$L = (L\bmod k) + k\mathbb{Z}^n,$$

i.e. we can split the lattice into parts that are 0 $\bmod k$, and the rest of things.
It is well-known that for $L\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$ that is full-rank, that $k = \det L$ suffices.
In practice though, $\det L$ can be exponential in $n$, so we often want to restrict to lattices that are "more periodic", i.e. there is some $q$ (that is relatively small) such that $q\mathbb{Z}^n \subseteq L\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n$.
If such a $q$ exists, we call $L$ $q$-ary.

Anyway, for $q$-ary lattices, we can work not with the (infinite) lattice $L$, but with its reduction mod $q$, which is $L/q\mathbb{Z}^n$.
Here, we get a nice fixed-length encoding, as $|L/q\mathbb{Z}^n| \leq q^n$, so each lattice point is encodable in at most $n\log_2 q$ bits.
For $q = \mathsf{poly}(n)$ (typical), this means we can represent lattice points with space quasi-linear in $n$.

If we removed this finite index (= full rank) property, this would no longer be true, and we would have to use a variable-length encoding to represent lattice elements, which would cause security issues.
So it is more than just a mathematical coincidence.

Comment: Each paragraph was new and informative for me: Leech lattice, importance of periodicity, introducing $q$-ary lattice in this way, and the security leak. Just one question: **most** lattices are periodic in the sense that was written. But **all** of them are periodic structures that we can use some tools like Fourier transform to analyzing them, Is that true?

Comment: All of them are periodic, I just don't have access to the precise reference for the general case. I think for full-rank $L\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, we get something like $(\det L)^2 \mathbb{Z}^n\subseteq L$, i.e. these are still periodic in the sense I mentioned (though with larger constant $(\det L)^2\geq \det L$). One cannot hope for such a simple expression for non-full rank lattices because any containment $c\mathbb{Z}^n\subseteq L$ implies $L$ is full-rank, but in cryptography we typically work with full-rank lattices, so this doesn't really matter.